# Drupal installing another language

Tags: drupal

I Downloaded the http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/nl-6.x-1.5.tar.gz file from Drupal Translations page. The readme file says to "Copy (merge) the content of this translation package into your Drupal installation root directory".

If i look at the package it has a few text files and a modules, profiles and themes folders. If I copy those in the root (so MAMP/sitename/) it overwrites a bunch of files (there are already modules and themes folders there ...)  and whatever page I load on the site gives fatal errors.

Is it possible that on MAMP / Mac Unarchiver doesn't do copy/merge but actually Replaces the old modules folder with this new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should happen, is that the relevant .po files are places in the folders where they should be. If things go wrong, what you'll end up having, would be a folder with all the .po's, in a nested set of folders.

In theory I guess it's possible to overwrite folders etc, but you would be opted to allow that first.

So you shouldn't be afraid that your entire Drupal install will be overwritten. You can just try to do the unpack and see what happens. Worst case, is that you'll need to place the files in the correct folders yourself.

Comment: The issue was with Unarchiver: it doesn't have a "merge" option, just replaces the files (!!!). The translations folders had to be copied manually one by one, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Unarchiver, but if you're overwriting files then something's not behaving correctly. All the translation packs really do is *add* some additional files and folders (e.g. `/modules/user/tranlsations/modules-user.nl.po` to `/modules/user`).

My guess is that your whole `/modules/user` directory (along with all the others) is being replaced, rather than added to.

Have you tried merging the folders in Terminal? You should be able to merge these folders directly from `tar`. Comment back if you would like more detailed instructions on how to do that.